# Unity / Panel Managment

Tags: unity, panel

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I would like to unite the unity panel with the top status panel in one panel...

What I'm trying to do is to make a single panel, something Windows-like. Is this possible to do without switching to XFCE or installing another docky/panel and hide the unity panel?

I tried some solutions, and I'm not satisfied with XFCE. I don't want to change icons or theme: I simply want to unite these two panels.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Simple answer is you do not, it's like this by design.

Answer (score 0):

Local menu of unity is a replacement for title menu of windows.

[image: Enable local menu in system setting panel]